# perl XML::LibXML utf8 encoding

Tags: xml, perl, utf-8

I am using perl module XML::LibXML.

XML::LibXML get string, which contains whole xml file with utf8 encoding.
I get information from xml using *findnodes* and *textContent*.
But when I try to print them into HTML page using *charset=UTF-8* it comes with bad characters like "�".
When I dont use *charset=UTF-8* in head of html page, it is correct but rest of page,which I print manually, is wrong.
Can you please help me to figure it out?

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it should, `textContent` returns the text in its "decoded" form (Unicode Code Points). File handles expect bytes, so you need to encode the text into bytes. You can instruct Perl to do so for you using

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

Comment: It works fine, but when I used it on the top in my own module and then use this module in some script, script automatically use this and rest of page is wrong again. Is there a way to tell script - dont use "use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';"??
Hope you understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have on the top of your script :

```
use utf8;
binmode $_, ":utf8" for qw/STDOUT STDIN STDERR/;
```

Comment: The `binmode` statement is better written as `use open qw/ :std :utf8 /`, although it also sets the default mode for any other `open` statements in the program.